# React-router-dom nesting to children component directly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nested, react-router-dom

I am new to react.js, now I used antd and react-router-dom to start my page.

Here I meet question which is related to react-router-dom, the structure of the router will be shown as below:

```
-Home 
-Member 
----MemberIquire 
----MemberExamine 
-Charge
----Investor
-------InvestorIncome
-------InvestorExpense
```

the mapping path is :

```
-(path: / )
-(path: /memebers )
----(path: /memebers/memberinquire ) 
----(path: /memebers/memberinquire ) 
-(path: /charge )
----(path: /charge/investor ) 
-------(path: /charge/investor/investorIncome ) 
-------(path: /charge/investor/investorExpense )
```

Here are my code:

```
/// main.jsx


<Router>
        <Layout className={styles["homepage-main"]}>
          <SideMenu />
          <Layout>
            <HeaderComponent />
            <Content className={styles["homepage-content"]}>
              <Route path="/dashboard" component={DashBoard}></Route>
              <Route
                path="/members/memberInquire"
                component={MembersInquire}
              ></Route>
              <Route
                path="/members/memberExamine"
                component={MembersExamine}
              ></Route>
            </Content>
          </Layout>
        </Layout>
</Router>
```

```
/// sideMenu.jsx
{menus.map((menu) => {
          if (!menu.subMenu) {
            // only first level
            return (
              <Item key={menu.key}>
                <Link to={`${menu.path}`}> {menu.name} </Link>
              </Item>
            );
          } else {
            // if it has second level
            return (
              <SubMenu key={menu.key} title={menu.name}>
                {menu.subMenu.map((s) => {
                  // only second level
                  if (!s.sunMenu) {
                    return (
                      <Item key={s.key}>
                        <Link to={`${menu.path}${s.path}`}> {s.name} </Link>
                      </Item>
                    );
                  }
                  // if it has third level
                  else {
                    return (
                      <SubMenu key={s.key} title={s.name}>
                        {s.sunMenu.map((ss) => {
                          return (
                            <Item key={ss.key}>
                              <Link to={`${menu.path}/${s.path}/${ss.path}`}>
                                {ss.name}
                              </Link>
                            </Item>
                          );
                        })}
                      </SubMenu>
                    );
                  }
                })}
              </SubMenu>
            );
          }
        })}
```

I had referred to react-router-dom official example for nesting, it used `let { path, url } = useRouteMatch();` in Topic function component.

But in my case, the `Members` is just only drop-down to open its children components (MemberIquire/MemberExamine) which means there is no component of `Members`, if follow my code it will always add `members` into URL when I click the link of MemberIquire or MemberExamine, so it will become `http://localhost:3002/#/members/members/members/members/memberExamine`

my wish is `http://localhost:3002/#/members/memberExamine` or `http://localhost:3002/#/members/memberIquire` when click.

please someone to help me to achieve this goal.
What if any confuse of this topic, please let me know, I will explin it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had found a solution for this case already, leave the answer to hope for someone who meets the same issue in the future.

**Question Description :**

1. I have a router json file to store every route information like this:

```
// route.js

const menus = [
  {
    key: "dashboard",
    name: "DashBoard",
    path: "/dashboard",
    // component: DashBoard
  },
  {
    key: "members",
    name: "MemberManage",
    path: "members",
    subMenu: [
      {
        key: "memberInquire",
        name: "MemberInquir",
        path: "memberInquire",
        // component: MemberInquire
      },
      {
        key: "memberExamine",
        name: "MemberExamine",
        path: "memberExamine",
        // component: MemberExamine
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

As you saw, this is a nested route structure.
What I want to realize is toggle url on click event.

```
click dashboard => url :www.example.com/dashboard
click memberInquire => url: :www.example.com/members/memberInquire
```

2. So I use `Link` of react-router-dom to access this tag.

```
<Link to={`${menu.path}/${s.path}`}>{s.name}</Link>
```

But, when I click the button of the menu between **memberInquire** and **memberExamine**, url starts to lose control.

```
My expectation: www.example.com/members/memberInquire
In fact: www.example.com/members/members/members/members/memberInquire
```

**Solution :**

The reason is due to **Link** behavior.
Actually, **Link** is just a `<a>` tag which has `push` way.
So what if I use Link like below:

```
<Link to={`${menu.path}/${s.path}`}>{s.name}</Link>
```

So that it will just tell the browser to push **members/memberInquire** when it is clicked every time.

To add **/** at beginning to become this :

```
           v
<Link to={`/${menu.path}/${s.path}`}>{s.name}</Link>
```

That will solve this issue :)